# Looping with SQL statements

Tags: sql

I am trying to implement a small logic in SQL:

For example : I have two tables A and B

```
    A            B
ID  Qnt         ID  Qnt   Value
1    50         1   100   1000      
2   130         2   200   1000
3   180         3   300   1000
4   320         4   400   2000
5   500         5   500   2000
                6   600   2000
                7   700   2000
```

I would to loop through each value of **Qnt in TABLE A** and check if the value lie between the range of the values in **Qnt of TABLE B** and get the corresponding value.

I know how I could achieve this with using While loop. But I don't want to do this since looping affects my query performance significantly. I would like to do this with only SQL statements.
Can anyone suggest an idea how I could go with this? just an idea would be great! Any sql would be fine, I would like to know just the logic.

The output would look like :

```
Output
ID      Qnt     Value
1       50      1000
2       130     1000
3       180     1000
4       320     2000
5       500     2000
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL? Or SQL Server? They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: Well, I do not need the script. Basically I just need the logic on how I could solve this with SQL statements. Anything wozld be fine to undersatnd.

Comment: Which can vary by vendor. I'm removing the specific tags since you are looking for a generic solution.

Comment: @John thanks for the info. Any suggestions with this one?

Comment: Yes a while loop is a bad idea for this case. Unless you needed to actually perform something with each value you never want to use a loop to do a simple query. Its basically called a subqery. And @GordonLinoff has a perfect solution posted below.

Comment: @logixologist It seems really simple to implement this with loop constructs which is similar to programming. But Gordan solution really seems to work. Trying out!

Comment: @SangameshHs think of it this way. You have a room full of 2000 people and you want to find your friend Raj. You know he is in room B. Doing It with loops is like saying you will go into each room and individually ask for his name, eventually you fill find Raj in Room B. Doing it with a subquery, you walk in to Room B and say, "Is Raj in this room". It will find Raj a lot sooner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a lookup.  You can do it with a correlated subquery, although the syntax is a bit different in the two databases.  Here is the MySQL version:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.value
        from b
        where b.qnt <= a.qnt
        order by b.qnt desc
        limit 1
       ) as value
from a;
```

Here is the SQL Server version:

```
select a.*,
       (select top 1 b.value
        from b
        where b.qnt <= a.qnt
        order by b.qnt desc
       ) as value
from a;
```